# Disponibilização da API do Stack Exchange para o Stack Overflow em Português

Tags: suporte, status-pronto, api

O Stack Overflow em Português será incluído na rede de sites disponíveis para o uso da [API do Stack Exchange](http://api.stackexchange.com/)? Se sim, existe alguma previsão de quando isso deve ocorrer?

Comment: Acho (apenas acho, meio que estou chutando) que o primeiro passo para isso é tornar o site público. Ainda estamos em estado beta privado.

Answer (score 5):

Não sei desde quando, mas já está disponível. O site aparece na 3ª página desta consulta:

> http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/sites?page=3&pagesize=100

Notando que as timestamps correspondem a

```
closed_beta_day: 12 dezembro 2013
open_beta_day:   29 janeiro  2014
```

[image: api result]

Aqui, um consulta das perguntas com mais votos no site:

> http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?order=desc&sort=votes&site=pt.stackoverflow

E fica o registro também do Data Explorer para consultar o banco de dados diretamente. Segue um exemplo com as perguntas com mais visitas nos últimos 3 meses <sup><sub>***(notando que os dados são [atualizados uma vez por semana](http://data.stackexchange.com/help))***</sub></sup>:

> http://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/206644/questions-with-most-views-created-within-3-month-range#resultSets

Answer (score 4):

O SOPT vai ser como todos os outros sites da rede, vai estar disponível na API e no SEDE. Mas antes, como o Victor disse, ele tem que sair do beta.

Comment: O que leva à questão: há alguma previsão para saída do beta?

Comment: Quero dizer, do beta privado ao público. Cf. http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/336/beta-privado-ate-quando

Comment: @bfavaretto Tem. Esse site é diferente, tem uma planejamento diferente, e vocês vão ter detalhes essa semana.

Comment: Esse planejamento diferente é justamente o que estamos querendo saber: http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/141/como-nosso-site-sera-graduado :)

Comment: @bigown Se eu falar tudo, estraga a surpresa. Essas perguntas vão ter algumas respostas em breve