# Alguém se opõe a debater o SOPT no metão neste momento?

Tags: debate, comunidade

Estou pensando em compartilhar no metão minha experiência no SOPT até o momento, mas como o site parece cheio de [segredos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314/disponibilizacao-da-api-do-stackexchange-para-o-stackoverflow-em-portugues#comment829_451), queria saber se alguém se opõe – e não estou pensando somente no Gabe, o guardião dos segredos, mas em qualquer um que possa achar isso uma má idéia.

A intenção é apresentar o site para uma audiência mais ampla, sendo que parte dela declaradamente tem interesse neste processo de localização, cujo primeiro produto é o nosso site. Queria poder trocar experiências com gente que já participou do processo de criação de outros sites (este é o primeiro de que participo), e poder ouvir a opinião de diversos usuários de lá que costumam dar contribuições relevantes.

Parece uma boa idéia?

Comment: Não esqueça de nos avisar :)

Comment: Claro, aviso aqui mesmo, assim que eu tiver tempo de escrever e postar o tal depoimento – se ninguém se opuser.

Comment: Debater o que quer que seja nunca pode ser negativo. E no metão inegavelmente haverá mais visibilidade da própria SE. Não imagino argumentos contra.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal É que como estou um pouco [ansioso](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13093650#13093650) em relação ao site, talvez seja cedo demais para poder tirar qualquer conclusão. Aliás, certamente é cedo demais, então tenho dúvidas se uma discussão disparada pela empolgação seria produtiva neste momento, ou se é melhor segurar. Acho que no fundo é esse tipo de opinião que estou pedindo aqui.

Comment: O SOPT não é segredo pra ninguém... Não tem problema algum em ir lá no MSO comentar a respeito

Comment: @Gabe acho que ele está falando das novidades dos próximos dias. Não dá para revelar o que não se sabe, então ele pode ir lá falar o que quiser :)

Comment: Nem eu sei do que eu estava falando, @bigown. Acho que fiquei preocupado do Gabe se ofender, de parecer que estaria passando por cima dele. O fato é que estou com síndrome de abstinência de feedback.

Comment: na minha imaturidade no site, não consigo ver problemas.

Answer (score 3):

Eu acho importante **não** levar questões pra lá que poderiam ser debatidas aqui para não deixar de fora a comunidade que não escreve inglês, que no meu ver deve ter o mesmo direito de expressar a opinião do que o resto (senão subverte todo o sentido de ter um SO "localizado", não?).

Queira quer não, as decisões da equipe do SE também são influenciadas pelas informações que chegam até eles (óbvio, mas não se pensa muito por este ângulo normalmente). Como exemplo temos o caso "br" ou "pt", que só teve uma mudança de opinião quando chegou lá, mas como mero resultado do que foi discutido e "pseudo-votado" aqui no nosso meta, que foi a base dos argumentos.

Vejam também o que eu comentei [nesta questão](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214277/foreign-language-meta-questions-shouldnt-be-migrated/) do "metão".

Reportar a experiência lá, acho até válido, desde que não tire o nosso meta das decisões.

> Em resumo: acho importante sim ir pro "metão" com os assuntos, mas levar o que temos discutido aqui como referência, e não discutir lá.

Edit: o que eu fiz, como exemplo, nas discussões do nosso meta em inglês, foi usar *flag* para chamar atenção do *staff*, como [nesse caso](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/496/auto-comment-posted-on-flagged-post-need-to-be-translated)

Comment: Eu penso em reportar lá por querer ouvir e atingir gente que não fala português. O problema principal que posso debater aqui é a própria falta de feedback. Vou postar sobre isso, acho que merece mesmo.

Comment: Eu realmente acho bom usar o "metão" pra transmitir em inglês o que acontece aqui, isso tem se mostrado eficiente pra fazer as coisas acontecerem. Só não queria invalidar nosso meta como maneira de resolver as coisas, justamente para sustentar a filosofia do site e a competência da nossa comunidade, além de não excluir os nossos não-falantes em inglês (não fosse por eles, não precisariamos de pt.SO)