# Auto-comment posted on flagged post need to be translated

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução

These messages are being posted automatically to novice users when the post is flagged. This comment seems strange to those who don't understand english, forcing us to translate it every time.

I think this translation is an urgent issue to solve.

[image: comment]

Suggestion: "Mesmo que este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e manter o link como referência. Respostas somente com link podem perder a validade caso o link mude."

---

Estas mensagens estão sendo postadas automaticamente para usuários novatos quando o post é sinalizado. Este comentário fica estranho para quem não entende inglês, nos obrigando a traduzi-lo todas as vezes.

Eu acho que esta tradução é um problema urgente a resolver.

Comment: Besides the vote up, I agree with the clarity of the wording on the proposed translation. Alem do voto positivo, concordo com a clareza das palavras escolhidas na tradução.

Comment: thanks, I'm working on it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The strings have been internationalized and sent to the translators. They will appear in Portuguese shortly.

---

Os textos foram internacionalizados e enviados aos tradutores. Aparecerão em Português em breve.